# how to make text bubbles only be the big enough to cover text, and also align on the correct sides?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, chat

I am trying to make a chat feed that has different text bubble colors depending on who sent the message. I also want the bubbles to be on opposite sides of the page, and only be big enough to take up the space of the text content. It should look like this:

[image]

But currently I have something that looks like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to accomplish this? Here's my current code:

```js
const chatMessages = [
  { username: "Bob", text: "hello" },
  { username: "jake", text: "hello to you too" },
  {
    username: "jake",
    text:
      "lLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eaque possimus itaque autem enim facere, inventore, a cum rem beatae dolores consectetur molestias maxime? Asperiores quisquam reiciendis ducimus minima! Fugit.",
  },
];

// formate an individual text into html element to be rendered
function textToHtml(textObj) {
  const textElement = document.createElement("div");
  const textContent = document.createTextNode(textObj.text);
  textElement.appendChild(textContent);

  if (textObj.username !== "jake") textElement.classList.add("other-user");
  else textElement.classList.add("me-user");
  return textElement;
}

const chatFeed = document.querySelector(".chat-feed");

chatMessages.forEach((text) => {
  chatFeed.appendChild(textToHtml(text));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.name-tag {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chat-feed {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.text-send {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

#text-bar {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.other-user {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.me-user {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(72, 151, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="name-tag">
        <h2>Bob</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-feed"></div>
      <div class="text-send">
        <form id="text-bar">
          <textarea form="text-bar" placeholder="Type to text..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For width: width:** min-content;

**For blue background messages, do this:** margin-left auto;

Answer (score 0):

I used a one column grid and set one of the element's `margin-left:auto` to push it to the other side. then gave them `display:inline-block` and the proper width.

```js
const chatMessages = [{
    username: "Bob",
    text: "hello"
  },
  {
    username: "jake",
    text: "hello to you too"
  },
  {
    username: "jake",
    text: "lLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eaque possimus itaque autem enim facere, inventore, a cum rem beatae dolores consectetur molestias maxime? Asperiores quisquam reiciendis ducimus minima! Fugit.",
  },
];

// formate an individual text into html element to be rendered
function textToHtml(textObj) {
  const textElement = document.createElement("div");
  const textContent = document.createTextNode(textObj.text);
  textElement.appendChild(textContent);

  if (textObj.username !== "jake") textElement.classList.add("other-user");
  else textElement.classList.add("me-user");
  return textElement;
}

const chatFeed = document.querySelector(".chat-feed");

chatMessages.forEach((text) => {
  chatFeed.appendChild(textToHtml(text));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.name-tag {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chat-feed {
  display:grid; /*Created a grid and gave it columns and rows*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: min-content;
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.text-send {
  display: inline-block; /*set the display to inline block so that the element doesn't stretch and behave as block*/
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

#text-bar {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.other-user {
  width: max-content;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 40%; /*changed it just to look better*/
}

.me-user {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left:auto; /*to push it to the right*/
  background-color: rgb(72, 151, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="name-tag">
      <h2>Bob</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-feed"></div>
    <div class="text-send">
      <form id="text-bar">
        <textarea form="text-bar" placeholder="Type to text..."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left:auto` with `display:table`

Note: if you want to make this pointer edge on bubble do let me know

```js
const chatMessages = [
  { username: "Bob", text: "hello" },
  { username: "jake", text: "hello to you too" },
  {
    username: "jake",
    text:
      "lLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid eaque possimus itaque autem enim facere, inventore, a cum rem beatae dolores consectetur molestias maxime? Asperiores quisquam reiciendis ducimus minima! Fugit.",
  },
];

// formate an individual text into html element to be rendered
function textToHtml(textObj) {
  const textElement = document.createElement("div");
  const textContent = document.createTextNode(textObj.text);
  textElement.appendChild(textContent);

  if (textObj.username !== "jake") textElement.classList.add("other-user");
  else textElement.classList.add("me-user");
  return textElement;
}

const chatFeed = document.querySelector(".chat-feed");

chatMessages.forEach((text) => {
  chatFeed.appendChild(textToHtml(text));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.name-tag {
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chat-feed {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.text-send {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

#text-bar {
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.other-user {
  border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    border-radius: 22px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.me-user {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(72, 151, 255);
  border-radius: 22px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="name-tag">
        <h2>Bob</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-feed"></div>
      <div class="text-send">
        <form id="text-bar">
          <textarea form="text-bar" placeholder="Type to text..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```